# "Base abstract generic class is a bad choice in most situations." Why? (Or Why not)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have just seen on the comment to a [blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/01/25/immutability-and-inheritance/) post:

> Base abstract generic class is a bad
>   choice in most situations

Is this true, if not why?

What insight(s) leads to this statement?

Comment: You should probably ask [the author of said comment](http://chabster.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Why don't you ask the author? Random blog comments without proper justification is not like the real truth. In some contexts it might be quite true, in others, not.

Comment: Even if it's a comment in a random blog, it's still interesting to see what SO users have to say in the subject.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*"Most situations"* is outrightly vague. A generic abstract class (or interface) is a bad idea **if** the only common ancestor between descendants of such class is System.Object (as noted by other commenters of this question).

Otherwise (as in, if you do have a meaningful common ancestor), it's a good idea if you want to "rename" or "specialize" members. Consider this example:

```
// Meaningful common ancestor for the working classes.
interface IWorker
{
   object DoWork();
}

// Generic abstract base class for working classes implementations.
abstract WorkerImpl<TResult> : IWorker
{
   public abstract TResult DoWork();

   object IWorker.DoWork()
   {
      return DoWork(); // calls TResult DoWork();
   }
}

// Concrete working class, specialized to deal with decimals.
class ComputationWorker : WorkerImpl<decimal>
{
    override decimal DoWork()
    {
       decimal res;

       // Do lengthy stuff...

       return res;
    }
}
```

In this example, `DoWork()` was redefined in the abstract class, becoming concrete and specialized in `ComputationWorker`.

Comment: It comes down to the semantics of his comment, or the definition of a base class. In my answer, I assumed that a "base class" does not inherit (or implement) anything. An abstract class that implements an interface does not function as a base class since other classes may share an ancestor (the interface).

Comment: As a side note, naming a base class "BaseSomething" or "AnythingBase" is my programming pet peeve!

Comment: @jamietre correctly, it's all about semantics. In the sense you described, it's really cumbersome to have such generic abstract base class. But consider the "base motivator" of this question (Jon Skeet's article). His abstract base class is a descendant of IEnumerable<T>! I think his grumpy commenter could have had this in mind.

Comment: Yeah I did notice that later (when I actually read the blog post :) and edited my answer to the effect that his grumpy commenter doesn't have a leg to stand on. But I think for the purposes of this discussion (which is wonderfully geeky I might add, perfect for a Friday) and the OP's general question, it worthy of debate. I tried to find a meaningful definition of "base class" btw after reading your comment. Couldn't find anything authoritative, and it gets used sloppily across the board.

Comment: @jamietre: By your definition, no class is an abstract base class (generic or not), because the only base class is `System.Object`.

Comment: Well, every element inherits proton, neutron, and electron, but they are still elements and not molecules. I would define base class as one that has no ancestors other than "object".

Comment: @jamietre: You're confusing "is-a" and "has-a" relationships.

Comment: I understand the distinction. But I think that calling something a "base class"  in a non-relative way, and meaning that it cannot be derived from another class, but that it may or may not implement other interfaces, is of little value, since it does not distinguish it functionally from any other class. A class that implements an interface works with existing things designed for that interface. A class that inherits another class works with existing things designed for that class. *Both work with with existing things* but a class that neither implements nor inherits, cannot.

Answer (score 16):

I agree, because anything that inherits an abstract generic class will not be polymorphic with the base class. That is, if you have

`abstract class myBase<T>`

then you create

```
class myThing: myBase<thing>
class myOtherThing: myBase<otherThing>
```

you can't create methods that work against myThing and myOtherThing since they do not share an ancestor. There's no point in the base class being abstract, really, it might as well just be a class.

But if you have a base class

```
abstract class myBase
class myBase<T>: myBase
```

as is a common pattern for generic classes (like IEnumerable - using interfaces), then they all share myBase.

(edit) I just read the actual blog post - and actually, the comment is not really valid in that situation. The "abstract generic base class" he's referring to, `Range<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>` which inherits non-generic interface `IEnumerable`. So it's not really an "abstract generic base class." But generally I think it's true.

Comment: Are you referring to covariance, which should be possible in .NET 4.0 ?

Comment: @Frederik, I think that would only matter if `thing` and `otherThing` were derived from the same class.

Comment: +1 -- "There's no point in the base class being abstract, really, it might as well just be a class."

Answer (score 4):

One problem with abstract generic base class is that you can't type decorate :

```
public abstract class Activity<TEntity>
{
  public Activity() { }

  protected virtual object Implementation { ... }
}

public abstract class CompensableActivity<TEntity,TCompensation> : Activity<TEntity>
  where TCompensation : Activity<T>, new()
{
  public CompensableActivity() { }

  protected override object Implementation
  {
    get { new Wrapper(base.Implementation, Compensation); }
  }

  private Activity<TEntity> Compensation
  {
    get
    {
      var compensation = new TCompensation();
      if(compensation is CompensableActivity<TEntity,Activity<TEntity>)
      {
        // Activity<TEntity> "does not meet new() constraint" !
        var compensable = comp as CompensableActivity<TEntity, Activity<TEntity>>;
        var implement = compensable.Implementation as Wrapper;
        return implement.NormalActivity;
      }
      else { return compensation; }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Kragen makes a good point.  Anything that is less than 50% of your code is "the wrong choice in the majority of situations".

However, even though nowhere near 50% of your classes should be generic abstract base classes, it also isn't less of a good thing than any other language feature.

For example, `BindingList<T>` could be considered an abstract generic base class.  It's a generic container, and sorting requires you to derive from it and override `ApplySortCore`.

`KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>` doesn't just act like an abstract generic base class, it is one.  To use it you MUST derive from it and implement `GetKeyForItem`.

Comment: Both KeyedCollection and BindingList inherit non-generic interfaces.

Comment: @jamietre: Every type in .NET inherits from a non-generic class.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the crowd here. In some cases an abstract generic class is the best design.
A good example in .NET can be found in System.Collections.ObjectModel where the KeyedCollection allows you to override and implement a typed serializable dictionary collection easily!

I elided most of the code but this is the principle:

```
public class NameCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string, INamedObj>
{

    protected override string GetKeyForItem(INamedObj item)
    {
        return item.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, statistically speaking if someone asked me **"should I make this class an abstract generic class?"**, the answer would almost certainly be no - in 3 years of .Net development I think I can count the number of abstract classes that I've written that had generic type parameters on one hand.

Other than that I can't see any particular reason for an abstract generic class to be considered a Bad Thing - its just not that common.

Answer (score -2):

There are situations where an abstract base class is useful thing.

We have several .net applications that use different database engines.  Several sql server, a couple of mysql and a bunch of oracle apps.

We have a generic common database object which is based on an abstract class that is a factory that returns the proper database object in a factory setting based on the type of database.

That way if I am starting a new application, all I have to do is load this database object, pass in the type, pass in the connection string, and bam... i'm set...

I guess what I'm trying to say is it all depends on the context and how its actually used.

Comment: Read the question again. carefully.

Comment: I think the reason you were downvoted was that the question is specifically relating to *generic* (as in [.Net generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192.aspx)) abstract base class, not just an abstract base class, as you described.