# Convert Class<T> Where T : IMySampleInterface to Class<IMySampleInterface >

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert `Class<T> Where T : IMySampleInterface` to `Class<IMySampleInterface>`

Example:

```
public abstract class AbstractCommunication: ICommunication
{
    private ICommunicationCallback<ICommunication> callback = null;
    public void registerCommunicationCallback<T>(ICommunicationCallback<T> callback) where T : ICommunication
    {
        this.callback =  (ICommunicationCallback<ICommunication>)callback; //<--DOESNT WORK
    }
}
```

In my Example the following exception occurs: `System.InvalidCastException`

Edit:

```
public interface ICommunicationCallback<T> where T : ICommunication
{
    void onCommunicationCallback(T sender, String data);
}
```

why do i use this way: If  I have a base class that should implement for example two Callbacks than i could simply use the following:

```
public class TestClass : ICommunicationCallback<TestClass1>, ICommunicationCallback<TestClass2>
```

TestClass1:

```
public class TestClass1: AbstractCommunication
{

}
```

TestClass2:

```
public class TestClass2: AbstractCommunication
{

}
```

Edit:
"if T is always an ICommunication, then why keep it generic? – Davin Tryon 20 mins ago" Im locking at this point

Okay Without the generics i got the same error but different `System.InvalidCastException`:
(That is why i used generics in the first place - i remember now)

```
 public class DocumentTest : ICommunicationCallback<GetDocumentData>
    {
     public void callAsync()
{
     CommunicationFactory comFactory = new CommunicationFactory(communicationServiceClient);
                GetDocumentData getDocumentData = (GetDocumentData)comFactory.createCommunicationObject(CommunicationFactory.ENTITY_TYPE.GET_DOCUMENT_DATA,(ICommunicationCallback<ICommunication> ) this);

}

}

public interface ICommunicationCallback<ICommunication> 
{
    void onCommunicationCallback(ICommunication sender, String data);
}
```

I Think using generics is the only solution in my case - see:
"This feature works only for generic interfaces and delegates. If you implement a variant generic interface, the implementing class is still invariant. Classes and structs do not support variance in C# 4.0. 
So the following doesn’t compile: 
// List implements the covariant interface 
// IEnumerable. But classes are invariant. 
List list = new List(); // Compiler error here."
(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Comment: you need to define `<T>` at the class level, not at the method level.

Comment: in my case that doenst work... i'll explain shortly

Comment: if `T` is always an `ICommunication`, then why keep it generic?

Comment: Did you look at the following questions? [“Base abstract generic class is a bad choice in most situations.” Why? (Or Why not)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5040814/299327) and [Using generics in abstract classes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2359540/299327)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Problem. But I haven't used generics - I use the ICommunication Interface.

```
public interface ICommunicationCallback
{
    void onCommunicationCallback(ICommunication sender, CommunicationResultObject result);
}
```

This solution in my opinion isn't that elegant but it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface ICommunication
{
}

interface ICommunicationCallback<T>
{
}

class AbstractCommunicationCallback<T> : ICommunicationCallback<T>
{

}

abstract  class AbstractCommunication : ICommunication
{
    private ICommunicationCallback<ICommunication> callback = null;
    public void registerCommunicationCallback<T>(ICommunicationCallback<T> callback) where T : ICommunication
    {
        this.callback = (ICommunicationCallback<ICommunication>)callback; //<--DOESNT WORK
    }
}

class Communication : AbstractCommunication { 
}
```

and test method

```
public void Test()
    {
          AbstractCommunication comm = new Communication();
         AbstractCommunicationCallback<ICommunication> callback = new AbstractCommunicationCallback<ICommunication>();
        comm.registerCommunicationCallback(callback);
    }
```

working without error on .net framework 4, vs 2010

EDIT: some interesting info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx